# $.isArray() function some problems

Tags: jquery, arrays

I wanted if the `arr` is true alert true if not alert false. Where I actually making mistake I checked my code at `jslint` but I found only `alert` was used before it was defined. Thank you

```
var arr = [1,23,4,5];
if(arr.isArray()===-1){
 alert(' false ');
}else{
  alert(' true ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
if(!$.isArray(arr)){
```

instead of:

```
if(arr.isArray()===-1){
```

since **[$.isArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/)** take an argument which is an object to determine whether that object is an array or not:

```
var arr = [1, 23, 4, 5];
if (!$.isArray(arr)) {
    alert(' false ');
} else {
    alert(' true ');
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8Ncn/)**

Answer (score 0):

[isArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/) is return boolean value. Compare with false.

```
   var arr = [1,23,4,5];
    if(arr.isArray()===false){
     alert(' false ');
    }else{
      alert(' true ');
    }
```

OR simple

```
var arr = [1,23,4,5];
alert(arr.isArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

$.isArray(arr)
See below link

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/